# Word break on comma delimited list of a href tags with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've having an issue with words not wrapping from a list of comma delimited a href tags.  Here is an image showing the issue:

[image: words no wrapping]

As you can see the table is pushed out until the word is wrapped based on white space.  You can also see the issue from my site: http://thetoolsmith.com/free-themes/bootstrap/toolsmith-31/ace-admin The site is built with bootstrap so it's responsive and you may need to resize your browser window to reproduce the issue.

I've tried the following CSS rules on the  cell without any luck:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The HTML look like this:

```
<td style="
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;">
  <a href="http://localhost/thetoolsmith/tag/themes/admin/sort.downloads/page.1">admin</a>,
  <a href="http://localhost/thetoolsmith/tag/themes/dashboard/sort.downloads/page.1" class="m-l-5">dashboard</a>,
  <a href="http://localhost/thetoolsmith/tag/themes/free/sort.downloads/page.1" class="m-l-5">free</a>,
  <a href="http://localhost/thetoolsmith/tag/themes/github/sort.downloads/page.1" class="m-l-5">github</a>,
  <a href="http://localhost/thetoolsmith/tag/themes/wrap-bootstrap/sort.downloads/page.1" class="m-l-5">wrap bootstrap</a>
</td>
```

Any CSS tricks I can use to break the href tags on the comma so it wraps and doesn't push the table out of alignment?

Comment: There are no spaces after your commas so the browser thinks your links are just one long word. Add a space at the end of each line.

Comment: Wow...can't believe I missed that.  I would see a space when viewing the page but when inspecting the element it wasn't there.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Jeffrey Jenkinson** for pointing it out but the string was missing a space delimiter between tags.